# How do I remove gaps caused by uneven heights in components when using Material Ui Grid?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, frontend

Im quite new to react and mui design thus im facing some issue in the logic of implemeting the layout.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";

const Item = styled(Paper)(({ theme }) => ({
  backgroundColor: theme.palette.mode === "dark" ? "#1A2027" : "#fff",
  ...theme.typography.body2,
  padding: theme.spacing(1),
  textAlign: "center",
  color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
}));

export default function RowAndColumnSpacing() {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: "100%" }}>
      <Grid container spacing={0}>
        <Grid item xs={6}>
          <Item sx={{ height: "20vh" }}>1</Item>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={6}>
          <Item sx={{ height: "40vh" }}>2</Item>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={6}>
          <Item>3</Item>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={6}>
          <Item>4</Item>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Due to the uneven heights in the Item component there is a gap in "cells" column wise
[current layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AISgr.png).
I want to negate the gap between item 3 and item one, how do i go about doing so?

I have tried allignment and flex suggestions to no avail

Comment: You'll have more luck with Grid layout. Feel free to post working output code that demonstrates the issue.